# Customise link html from rich text

Tags: wagtail

Is there a way I can change the html output from a link stored in a paragraph in rich text? The current output is like that below and ideally, it would contain a custom attribute.

```
<p><a id="3" linktype="page">Home</a></p>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing @DNN - did you ever manage to do this?